# Can't install desired version of Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-6

I can't Install Laravel 6.0, when I run this command:

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel laravel_6.0
```

I want to install `v6.0` but it comes with `v5.8.17`.

How can I download the latest version of laravel? My `Php` version is `7.2.10`

Answer (score 2):

I recently, updated all of my projects to laravel 6.0,

[image: Laravel-6.0-Installation-Ubuntu]

I'm using, Ubuntu 19.04
by following command it works for my system

```
composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel your-project-name
```

Here are some few ways to install laravel by specifying version

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel=6.0 your-project-name --prefer-dist

composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel:6.0 your-project-name

composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel your-project-name "6.*"
```

Answer (score 1):

From today you can install laravel version 6 with this command:

```
composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel blog
```

Comment: :) Thank you for help, like always helping, <3 Happy Simplicity.

Comment: Thank you too @Vipertecpro :)

Comment: @Vipertecpro sorry to bother but what did you mean with "Happy Simplicity"?

Comment: Well as all frameworks moving up and upgrading, our coding styles becoming more minimal and of course simple.

Comment: Ok I understood, sorry but I am not a mother tongue, I agree with you.

Answer (score 0):

It's not loaded into Packagist as an official version yet. Therefore, you need to use the "dev-develop" version which contains the latest unstable commit from GitHub:

```
$ composer create-project laravel/laravel laravel_6.0 dev-develop
```

Answer (score -1):

re setup the composer. Show php 7 version when installing.